# Measure of the set of real numbers that can be approximated in this way

Tags: measure-theory, diophantine-approximation

Let $$A = \{x \in \mathbb{R}\mid \exists\,\text{infinitely many pairs of integers $p,q$ such that $|x-p/q| \leq 1/q^3$}\}.$$  Is the measure of $A$ equal to $0$?  Any ideas?

Comment: It is $0$. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number#Irrationality_measure .

Answer (score 2):

Let's restrict to $(0,1]$ and let $A_{q}=\bigcup_{p=1}^q B(\frac pq,\frac 1{q^3})$. Then $\mu(A_{p,q})\le \frac 1{q^2}$.
We are looking for 
$$ \mu(A\cap(0,1])\le \mu\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\bigcup_{q=n}^\infty A_q\right)\le \mu\left(\bigcup_{q=n}^\infty A_q\right)\le \sum_{q=n}^\infty\mu(A_q)\le\sum_{q=n}^\infty\frac1{q^2}.$$
Since the last expression is the tail of the convergent series $\sum_{q=1}^\infty\frac1{q^2}(=\frac{\pi^2}{6})$, it tends $\to0$ as $n\to\infty$. We conclude $\mu(A\cap(0,1])=0$ and as $A$ is the countable union of translated copies of $A\cap(0,1]$, we also have $\mu(A)=0$.

Comment: You probably meant $A_q\leq \frac{2}{q^2}$ in the first line (since the volume of a ball of radius $\frac{1}{q^3}$ is $\frac{2}{q^3}$), and consequently some other terms multiplied by $2$.